# How can I set up saving OBS stream to Google Drive or Dropbox or any other cloud file storage?

Tags: google-drive-api, streaming

So I want to record videos with Open Broadcast Software, but I lack the HDD fast and big enough to do so. However, streaming (such as to Twitch) works fine. How can I set it up so I stream it instead and the stream gets automatically saved to a cloud file storage like Google Drive or any other?

Answer (score 1):

Just stream to YouTube then use https://yt-dl.org/ to download your videos later.

Comment: If you're going to downvote a legit answer (this solution works 100% for me), perhaps you could explain why this doesn't work for you -- or phrase your question and situation better.